# How to pass login parameters to mysql

Tags: mysql, shell, unix

I have a shell script which calls the `mysql` command line client, it looks like this:

```
 $ cat ms
 mysql --host=titanic --user=fred --password="foobar"
```

It works OK:

```
$ ./ms 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 810
...
```

Now, I'd like to keep the script in a git repository, but without the user and password details. So, I thought I would have a file `SECRET` with: `--host=titanic --user=fred --password="foobar"` which I wouldn't add to the git repository, and change the `ms` script like this:

```
mysql $(cat SECRET)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I get this error when I run it:

```
$ ./ms
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'fred'@'example.com' (using password: YES)
```

I cannot understand it - when the `$(cat SECRET)` is evaluated/expanded it looks exactly the same as the straightforward invocation of `mysql`. Still, it doesn't work. The same happens if I try to do it directly in interactive shell:

```
$ mysql --host=titanic --user=fred --password="foobar"
```

works OK, but the below does not:

```
$ cat SECRET
--host=titanic --user=fred --password="foobar"
$ mysql $(cat SECRET)
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'fred'@'example.com' (using password: YES)
$ echo mysql $(cat SECRET)
mysql --host=titanic --user=fred --password="foobar"
```

Anybody can shed some light on what's going on here and how to fix it? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the file to:

```
--host=titanic --user=fred --password=foobar
```

Quotes aren't processed on the result of command or variable substitution, only word splitting and filename expansion are done.

But a better solution would probably be to use an [option file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html), e.g. mysecret.cnf:

```
[mysql]
user=fred
password=foobar
host=titanic
```

Then run mysql as:

```
mysql --defaults-file=mysecret.cnf
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick... Thank you! So now I understand that `mysql` got the password with the quotes, where normally the quotes are removed by shell...